# reformatting data to nice format

Tags: shell, awk

I have three columns of data that contain data as follows

```
26.77 12.477 -25 100
26.364 12.476 -20 100
26.372 11.47 -16 100
26.366 10.473 -10 100
26.158 10.472 -9 100
26.75 12.471 2 100
```

I want to reformat data to

```
26.770 12.477 -25 100
26.364 12.476 -20 100
26.372 11.470 -16 100
26.366 10.473 -10 100
26.158 10.472 -09 100
26.750 12.471  02 100
```

i tried below code but it did not work.

```
awk '{ printf("%.3g %.3g %.3g %.3g\n", $1, $2, $3, $4) }' in.dat
```

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code in your question, as your efforts, thank you.

Comment: Soo why not just `column -t`? Do you need the zeros?

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts. 2 questions here. Does 1st field always have 3 digits at max(after DOT) OR they can vary? And if they vary means(their length can go to 4,5 or 6 etc) o we need to add zeroes by looking the max 1st field length? Please confirm once.

Comment: Can your input ever contain values that aren't in NN.NNN format in the first 2 columns or NN in the third? e.g. could you have an input line like `6.372 1.470 -6 100`? If so, please [edit] your question to include examples of other formats so we can see how you expect those to be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you requested can be done with:

```
awk '{ printf("%.3f %.3f % 03.0f %.0f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4) }'
```

However I would just pipe it to `column -t` for "nice" format.